# How to stop both widgets in a stack from responding to touch

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Stack Widget which contains a map (covering the whole page) and a listview at the bottom and above the map. But when you swipe the listview, the map also moves. How do I stop the map from moving as well? The Listview is in front of the Map so I am unsure as to why the map also responds to me moving the listview.

```
Stack(
   children <Widget> [
      Map(),
      ListView( ... ),
   ]
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to move the map or keep it static?

Comment: I would like to be able to move the map but not when I'm sliding the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absorb pointer where you don't wish to pass the gesture to the map. In the stack use this heirarchy

```
Stack(
 children: [
  Map(),
  Positioned(
    bottom :0,
    child: AbsorbPointer(//this will absorb the pointer from going to the map
     child : Container(
       height: 300 // edit this to the required height
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
     )
   )
  ),
 // Listview here
]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widget to wrap the map

```
IgnorePointer(ignoring: false, ...)
```

and adjust this attribute by changing the bool value of ignoring:

Comment: I tried to do this but the map still moves

Comment: did you set the ignoring attribute to true

Comment: I tried both and but the map still moves as well